# Question edited but what was changed?

Tags: support, edits

In one of the Stackoverflow questions I posted I got a notification like below:

Code in your question New Syntax similar to Nullabletype from Dropthings? was edited.

But I could not figure out what was changed because all I remember sharing is a brief snippet of code.

Is there a way StackOverflow can also include a brief detail about the change on such edits if not a full versioning of the commits for the threads?

Answer (score 4):

You can view the revision history of a question (and thus see what was edited) when you click on the timestamp of the edit information below the post:

[image]

There you have three options to view the differences between certain revisions:

- <kbd>inline</kbd> displays all changes in once place. *You see the rendered output* of the post.
- <kbd>side-by-side</kbd> displays the old version on the left and the new on the right side. *You see the rendered output* of the post. On the left side removed parts are highlighted, on the right side added parts are highlighted.
- <kbd>side-by-side markdown</kbd> displays the old version on the left and the new on the right side. *You see the markdown* of the post (the source-code). On the left side removed parts are highlighted, on the right side, added parts are highlighted.

There is more information about syntax highlighting available in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

The revision history for you question is [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15619352/revisions). In revision 2, four blanks have been added to enable syntax-highlighting for the code you wrote.

Comment: Interestingly the two statements does not seem to carry any differences. Copy-Pasting them onto Notepad just shows up as below:

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["t"] ?? string.Empty
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["t"] ?? string.Empty

Looks like something a false-positive alert?

Comment: View them using the side-by-side-markdown view. There have been added four blanks before your line of code, to enable syntax highlighting (as [explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks))